# Website "you can do this" script

Tags: database

I want to create a training path for new users accessing my site. This training path must display info bubbles showing what you can do on every page, but only the first time you access it.

So, for example, if a user enters a page where there's an edit button an info box should appear next to the edit button telling the user that he can edit that page.

I will create the script myself, I just want to know what's the best method to check if the user has already seen that box or not. I was thinking about storing in database a boolean value for each info box which will be set to true if the user has seen the box. To save some queries from the DB I think I can also store the same values in localStorage or in Cookies.

What is the best practice for creating user training paths for a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I suggest is to store user id (ip or username ? ) and a bit value for each bubble like you say.

PS: for your script you can use this:
http://www.maxvergelli.com/jquery-bubble-popup/documentation/

Jérôme

Comment: Yeah, but my question is. Where to store that value? I don't want to make a DB reqeuest every time the user refreshes a page. Is there a better option than saving the values in localStorage?

Comment: Why you need to make a DB request every time they refresh the page? You should make the access once, cache the value.

Comment: You store in cookies but problem is to store on a permanent way. You can set cookies and update Database on the logout click for example. But what if user don't click on 'sign out'. You can set cookies and update database every X seconds.